# sftp batch file not able to execute

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have a windows batch file to connect from Server A (Windows) to Server B (UNIX) via sftp to get a file. The script is as below:

```
sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=EAPIINSTADM_hostnameA ftpeapsg@hostnameB
lcd D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG
get GENUOBGW1 /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG
exit
```

When I run the script it stops after running the first line i.e sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no...

```
D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG>sftpg3 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oIdentityFile=EAPIINSTADM_hostnameA ftpeapsg@hostnameB
Warning: ignoring unsupported option -o
Warning: ignoring unsupported option -o
Remote system type is POSIX.
sftp>
```

It didn't execute below lines:

```
lcd D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG
get GENUOBGW1 /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG
```

If I run the command manually one line at a time it works.

Any idea why the script does not run completely?

Thank you.

Comment: You have [already posted this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57265268/850848). And you already got an answer there. So why are you crossposting the question again here? (crossposting is forbidden btw).

Answer (score 2):

Batch files **do not imitate keyboard input.** They start programs and *wait for those programs to finish*; the whole script is paused until you exit out of sftpg3, and the following lines (lcd, get) will be run as independent commands.

If your sftp client has its own "batch script" option, use that (e.g. OpenSSH has `sftp -b`, WinSCP has a whole `winscp.com` meant for scripting).

```
sftp -b ftpcommands.txt eapsg@hostname
```

If it does not, you can provide input using *redirection*, i.e. the `<` operator:

```
sftpg3 eapsg@hostname < ftpcommands.txt
```

Providing commands inline *might* work using a pipe (though not as convenient as `<<` in Unix shells):

```
(echo lcd D:\APPBASE\EAPSG\GEMSSG & echo get GENUOBGW1 /sftp/ftphrssg/HRSSG/EAPSG) | sftpg3 host
```